# Using tailwind css and bootstrap together in a laravel application

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, tailwind-css

I have a small (and maybe dumb) question. I am working on my final year project and I was wondering if I can use bootsrap and tailwind css together. I know that they can be used together, I am not asking how to, I am asking if its bad practice or if it will impact the application in a bad way (maybe slowing it down since the app.css is twice as long). I have worked with both of them in the past and I would like to use tailwind on some pages and bootsrap on others. Any advice on this will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can use both Tailwind css and Bootstrap 4 at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62688037/can-use-both-tailwind-css-and-bootstrap-4-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, it is better not to use too much css in a page for both reasons you mentioned: **speed** and **compatibility**.

If you are sure about the compatibility, then it leaves the speed issue.
It is all about a compromise between optimization and ease of implementation which is very subjective.