# Can use both Tailwind css and Bootstrap 4 at the same time?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-component, tailwind-css

My project is currently Vuejs which use BootstrapVue components (seems to use bootstrap 4 css).

I am trying to use Tailwind css for new custom components.

Is it possible to use both of them at same time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can solve classes conflict using a prefix

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  prefix: 'tw-',
}
```

**BUT**, most likely you will have a problem with `normalize.css`, which used in `@tailwind base`

Comment: hi, can i know why normalize.css will cause a problem and why should we disable it by preflight: false?

Answer (score 17):

**Option 1: Adopt or recreate classes**

If you only need one or two classes, for example from the [color system of Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors), you could also copy them.
Some characters would have to be masked, e.g:

// style.css

```
.hover\:text-blue-900:hover,
.text-blue-900 {
  color: #183f6d;
}
```

*That's what I did at the beginning of a project, where bootstrap is the main *framework*.*
If it should be several colors and functions, you can also build this with SCSS quickly. **In the long run, however, in my opinion, not the best and cleanest solution.**

Example for this:

// style.scss

```
(...)
@each $name, $hexcode in $tailwind-colors {
    .hover\:text-#{$name}:hover,
        .text-#{$name} {
            color: $hexcode
        }
    }
}
```

[Full code (Github Gist)](https://gist.github.com/juliankasimir/e92e879812a05e5b818ba37690332c60)

**Option 2: Integrate Tailwind**

But as soon as more functionalities should be added, or you want to build it cleaner, you can do here with the prefix mentioned by the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix) as [Ostap Brehin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8121797/ostap-brehin) says.

// tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  prefix: 'tw-',
}
```

The normalized definitions can be removed by [disabling preflight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#disabling-preflight):

// tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  }
}
```

*Better check the generated CSS file.*

Here is my full [tailwind.config.js](https://gist.github.com/JulianKasimir/d683ea15a83cd1e229c2fbcbe3637c47) file:

// tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    content: [
        './**/*.php',
        '../Resources/**/*.{html,js}',
    ],
    safelist: [
        'tw-bg-blue-800/75',
        {
            pattern: /(bg|text)-(blue)-(800)/,
            variants: ['hover'],
        },
    ],
    prefix: 'tw-',
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    corePlugins: {
        preflight: false,
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Or just use https://unocss.dev/

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can use Tailwind and Bootstrap together.

However, you need to do some configuration to your tailwind. The first thing is to add a prefix and then turn off the preflight. And if you are not using Tailwind JIT then also make the important as true. If you are using Tailwind JIT then you can use "!" before the class to make it important. For example "!tw-block".

Here is a suitable configuration for Tailwind JIT/CDN:

```
  <script>
    tailwind.config = {
      prefix: "tw-",
      corePlugins: {
         preflight: false,
      }
    }
  </script>
```

If you are not using CDN, use this configuration:

```
module.exports = {
    content: ["./**/*.html"],
    prefix: "tw-",
    important: true,
    corePlugins: {
        preflight: false,
    }
}
```

I have written a whole blog on it: https://developerwings.com/tailwind-and-bootstrap-together/

Comment: I tried this solution for the configuration and got both bootstrap and tailwind working together flawlessly.  One thing I'll add is that with "preflight: false" is that some of the tailwind UI components were not rendering properly.  In order to solve this I added a separate preflight css file and added a .preflight class to certain tailwind components.  This article explains how (https://dev.to/ajscommunications/scoping-normalized-preflight-css-c29)
Also, I used (https://github.vue.tailwind-prefix.cbass.dev/) to quickly add the "tw-" prefix to my tailwind code.

Answer (score 7):

Possible, **Yes**. Is it recommended, **NO**.

There are many classes that are gonna **contradict** with
each other e.g.

[.container (Bootstrap)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/#containers)

[.container (Tailwind)](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/container/#app)

[.clearfix (B)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/clearfix/)

[.clearfix (T)](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/float)

And the list goes on...

---

My advice would be to either stick with BootstrapVue or Tailwind. My personal preference, Tailwind.

Comment: Actually, I dont like to rewrite all bootstrapVue components again, though I love tailwind :(

Comment: is there any bootstrap like opinionated library built on top of tailwind with all the components like alert, grid, btns, cards, collapse, etc. sometimes you don't want to leave the comfort of bootstrap but want tailwind utilities at the same time

Comment: @SumitWadhwa DaisyUI seems to do that, but I haven't used it.

Comment: @SumitWadhwa Tailwind UI is the official offering for this, though it's a paid product. https://tailwindui.com/

Answer (score 3):

As long as there's no name collision in 2 libs (which I don't think they are), they will work just fine.

But I don't think you should. Because it will break the unification of the project and will make it harder to maintain.

Comment: There actually are quite a few name collisions as shown in other answers...

Answer (score 0):

> is there any bootstrap like opinionated library built on top of tailwind with all the components like alert, grid, btns, cards, collapse, etc. sometimes you don't want to leave the comfort of bootstrap but want tailwind utilities at the same time

That is pretty much what we were looking for. Finally found https://tw-elements.com/

> Bootstrap components recreated with Tailwind CSS, but with better design and more functionalities

It has an AGPL licence so you can use it for free as long as your project is open source.