# Can we apply tailwind CSS and react-bootstrap in the same project?

Tags: react-bootstrap, tailwind-css

I am working in my recent project. I want to add bootstrap and tailwind-CSS as an experiment in my project.

Comment: Tailwindcss and bootstrap are two similar but different CSS frameworks. It might not be possible to do this considering there is overlap between the two CSS class definitions. Can I ask why you want to do this? Tailwind would probably be a better choice over Bootstrap for a react app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can use both Tailwind css and Bootstrap 4 at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62688037/can-use-both-tailwind-css-and-bootstrap-4-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 2):

I am also kind of new to Stack Overflow but there is an example in another thread.
Here: [Can use both Tailwind css and Bootstrap 4 at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62688037/can-use-both-tailwind-css-and-bootstrap-4-at-the-same-time)

TL;DR It is possible but it is not recommended.

How to solve conflicts between classes? The link aformentioned contains a solution that should work since it was the accepted answer.

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
   prefix: 'tw-',
}
```